# Laravel- Auth::check returns false in the middleware for successfull login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, middleware

My login controller

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'error' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }
```

middleware that i check the auth

```
class AuthorizeUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return view('application');
        }
    }
}
```

`Auth::check()`  in this middleware returns false event the `Auth::attempt` was successful.
How do I find the cause of this issue?

Comment: Thank you all who supported. Problem was with my session configurations. I have previously set session driver as database and changed the session name also. I replaced session.php and .env by default configuration. Then above code worked perfectly. (I guess something went wrong with the session configuration and I will keep posted when I have time to look back that issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all who supported. Problem was with my session configurations.
I have previously set session driver as database and changed the session name also.
I replaced session.php and .env by default configuration. Then above code worked perfectly. (I guess something went wrong with the session configuration and I will keep posted when I have time to look back that issue)

Answer (score 3):

Put Your routes in Middleware of Auth or Web then it will works.

You can use this code in routes/api.php

```
 Route::post('your-route-here', [ControllerNameHere::class,'FunctionNameHere'])->name('Route-Name-Here')->middleware('api');
```

Or You can use in routes/web.php

```
 Route::post('your-route-here', [ControllerNameHere::class,'FunctionNameHere'])->name('Route-Name-Here')->middleware('web');
```

Comment: middleware is there and it get hits. issue is that Auth::check returns false always

Answer (score 1):

Check the `primary key` of your users database. If you set your table's primary key other than id, you need to set it in your User model.

The Laravel Documentation states the following:

```
Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention.
```

For example, if you have a user_id column set as your primary key in your users database, you need to place the code below in the User model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Comment: I don't use Eloquent.
`
    'providers' => [
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
        //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        // ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'student_user',
        ],
    ],`
this is the provider in auth.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you use any guard in auth.php?
Is this you default guard?

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
     'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: Yes this is my default guard

Answer (score 1):

Use `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware instead:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: how do I use this middleware. I want to redirect users that are not authenticated to the 'application' view